# User reboot notification script

Tags: vbscript, windows-7, windows-10

Would greatly appreciate any help about my concern below, I've been searching the internet about this for a long time..

I want to implement a user reboot notification script that will check if the user's machine has not been rebooted for more than 24hrs; if yes, it will give a message box with a choice to reboot now or remind them later for a certain period then it will pop up again. If the User has chosen remind them later for the 3rd time, the script will force a reboot with a countdown.

I'm thinking to deploy this via GPO as a scheduled task that will run everyday. If the user's machine meets the condition of they have rebooted within 24hrs, then it'll just do nothing.

Thanks!

---

I saw some script and modified it a bit.. it works but How can I add the succeeding Hour and Minutes after the Day? If I add another dateDiff to output the hour and minutes, I'm getting the whole day/s converted to hour/minutes..

```
'Set the minimum number of days of uptime to begin issuing the warning.
WarnAfterDays = 0

Set objShell = wscript.createObject("wscript.shell")
Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\.\root\cimv2")
set colComp = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select LastBootUpTime from Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each item in colComp
dlastReboot = WMIDateStringToDate(item.LastBootUpTime)
dDiff = dateDiff("d",dLastReboot,Now)

if dDiff >= WarnAfterDays Then

do while 1>0

intRebootChoice = MsgBox("This computer has been running for " & dDiff & " days since " & dlastReboot & ". To keep the computer operating optimally a system restart 

is recommended." & VBCRLF & VBCRLF & "PLEASE SAVE ALL YOUR WORK BEFORE RESTARTING." & VBCRLF & VBCRLF & "Would you like to restart your computer?" & VBCRLF & "[YES to 

retstart now, NO to be reminded later]",308,"NOTICE - REBOOT REQUIRED")

select case intRebootChoice
  case 6
   Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate,(Shutdown)}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
   Set colOperatingSystems = objWMIService.ExecQuery ("Select * from Win32_OperatingSystem")
   For Each objOperatingSystem in colOperatingSystems
    ObjOperatingSystem.Reboot(1)
   Next
  case 7
   wscript.sleep(30000)
 end select
loop
End if
Next

Function WMIDateStringToDate(dtmInstallDate)
WMIDateStringToDate = CDate(Mid(dtmInstallDate, 5, 2) & "/" & _
Mid(dtmInstallDate, 7, 2) & "/" & Left(dtmInstallDate, 4) _
& " " & Mid (dtmInstallDate, 9, 2) & ":" & _
Mid(dtmInstallDate, 11, 2) & ":" & Mid(dtmInstallDate, _
13, 2))
End Function
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to Stackoverflow :) Please take the [tour] and learn a bit about the site (will even give you a badge if you do so!). As Stackoverflow is not a free code-writing service you should show your effort and post some code that you have tried or a problem that you ran into during the programming (or even better both).

Comment: Please try a script yourself using `DateDiff` and `systeminfo | find /i "Boot Time"` first, and if a problem occurs, show us it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps consider using [PsShutdown](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/psshutdown.aspx). Install this on each workstation and you can set up some scheduled tasks to trigger it, or you can even use the management UI to remotely trigger shutdowns from the server. You can specify when to shut down, how much warning to give, a message to the user, and whether or not they can cancel. This will give you most of the features you need without writing any code at all.

[image]